# Python ssh - keep connection open after script terminates

Tags: python, linux, ssh, paramiko

I'm trying to write a script that will ssh into a box for me.  I'm using Python and leveraging the paramiko library.  I can successfully ssh on the box, but as soon as the script terminates, the ssh connection also terminates.  I want to keep the connection open after the script has completed running.

Python:

```
self.ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
self.ssh.connect(host, username=self.username, password=self.password)
stdout = execute(self.ssh, 'pwd') # test command for now to verify i'm on box
print stdout
sys.exit()
```

Console:

> $ ssh.py
>
> [u'/home/myuser\n']
>
> myuser@xxxx ~
>
> $

I haven't been able to find similar examples online, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To terminate my script

Comment: What do you want the connection to do after the script terminates?

Comment: I want the connection to remain open in the shell

Comment: Do you mean that you want an interactive connection, that you want to be able to type commands and have them interpreted by the remote shell?

Comment: Yes.  All I essentially want the script to do is run 'ssh myuser@myserver'.  After connecting, I want my script to exit and leave the terminal open with the ssh connection still alive, so I can do whatever manual things I need to do on that machine.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, but paramiko doesn't provide an interactive connection. Paramiko is for scripted activities. You probably just want `subprocess.call(["ssh", "myuser@myserver"])`.

Comment: To put it another way, the connection can't **remain** "open", since it never was "open' to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This will make my life much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["ssh", "myuser@myserver"])
```

Comment: Is it possible to include the password in the command so I don't have to re-type it in every time? Thanks

Comment: as for security reasons it is not possible to use a password within the ssh command, use ssh-keys instead (much more comfortable and secure)